# Custom 404 page not working

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'm trying to set a custom 404 page but is not working.
What I tried:

- configuration - system - basic site settings and set node path on 404 page -> didn't work
- add page--404.html.twig to my custom theme -> didn't work
- in my custom-theme.theme added _theme_suggestions_page_alter function -> didn't work

Always show default 404 page, not my custom page.
I clear cache on every attempt.
Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance

---

Edited

Tried on local and cloud acquia server

I check with another websites that I build and all of them give me this 404 page (default)
[image: default 404 page]

But with this specific website I get this 404 page
[image: 404 page]

It seems this website 404 error is handle by browser and not by drupal 8(?)

---

Edited 2

Another thing I notice is when I type a wrong URL appear on "log messages"

[image: log message]

But on current website (the one I can't set custom 404) I don't have any error on "log messages".

Is there any code/config to enable/disable this?

Maybe this is same problem?

Comment: Is it on Local or Remote server?

Comment: Tried on both, local and cloud acquia server

Comment: That screenshot looks like `devportal.dd` can't be mapped to an IP address (hostname unresolved) so the browser gives you 404. This has nothing to do with Drupal being able to find a page. Looks like your server isn't configured properly.

Comment: Is configured properly, because I can navigate and see everything on my website, when I type a wrong path to test 404 appear this page, instead of custom 404 or default 404 (like one on my "custom" website of my printscreen)
I thinks this is some code somewhere I can't find (I am updating this site, so I am not aware of all whats done here)

Comment: This is an empty 404 response with no text, then the browser displays a standard text. Obviously something on your site is sending such a response before Drupal has a chance to log the error and send a themed error page (whether this contains the Drupal standard text or a custom one doesn't matter).

Comment: @4k4 thanks for your input. Do you have any idea where I can find/start looking for this? This is mande by theme? settings? htaccess? modules? I'm a bit lost with this :/

Comment: This could be an attempt to serve fast 404's. Drupal 8 provides some basic fast 404 features configurable in settings.php, which are normally only used for certain file types. Then it could be a contrib module or custom code.

Comment: @4k4 Again thank you for your input, this help me solve the problem, looked into settings.php (because I don't have any custom/contrib module to do that), also I already have checked htaccess, and yes, some guy set fast 404. When you mentioned "fast 404" I search for that in my settings.php and voilla

Answer (score 1):

Are your sure you did all the steps? **Step 1: in mytheme.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'system.401':
      // Unauthorized Access.
      $error = 401;
      break;

    case 'system.403':
      // Access Denied.
      $error = 403;
      break;

    case 'system.404':
      // Page Not Found.
      $error = 404;
      break;
  }
  if (isset($error)) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $error;
  }
}
```

**Step 2: create the page--404.html.twig file**

**Step 3: clear cache**

For some markup, check https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/styling-404-error-pages-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I treid that function with my custom twig and didn't work :/ I found your link on my search for this error :)

Comment: Are you sure you used MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter and not MYTHEME_suggestions_page_alter?
update: After your edit I think this is a server-side issue.

Comment: Yes, I set MYTHEME_theme_suggestions and just to be sure also tried MYTHEME_suggestions. This could be some config from acquia cloud? In htaccess don't have any difference between this site and other's where custom 404 works

Comment: This can't be the issue here, the theme suggestion is in core since 8.8.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2960810

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who contrib to help me solve this problem.

Special thanks to @4k4 user, with some keywords and starting points I could found where my problem was.

It was in settings.php at "Fast 404 pages" function, I had this code:

[image: settings.php]

Commented this block and it works like charm.

Thanks @4k4 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
        $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
        $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
        $http_error_suggestions = [
            'system.401' => 'page__401',
            'system.403' => 'page__403',
            'system.404' => 'page__404',
        ];

        $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
        if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {
            $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
        }
}
```

Create the page template page--404.html.twig